# SDL2 2D texture allocation/pooling

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I have two questions regarding SDL2's hardware-accelerated texture rendering:

1. When using `SDL_Createtexture(...)`, are textures automatically pooled/transferred between system RAM and VRAM when VRAM is at a premium? In order to ensure I don't inundate VRAM, I was considering loading textures into surfaces and converting them to textures as and when required (it's unlikely that all textures will fit into VRAM at once).
2. When minimizing a fullscreen application and/or changing screen resolutions, will `SDL_Texture` instances need to be recreated?

Comment: "are textures automatically pooled/transfered between system RAM and VRAM" - Sorry, no magic.

Comment: `1` is up to graphics driver. As for `2` - you can lose *render* textures contents when device is lost (but texture itself should still be valid - just need to redraw it if it isn't updated every frame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to recreate your `SDL_Texture` instances after minimize a window or change its resolutions. Maybe you only need to redraw things in the screen after change its resolutions, but not after minimize it.

Also, I recommend you to look at these SDL2 tutorials:
https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php